# How do I validate a mobile number using Python?

Tags: python, regex, django

I'm trying to validate a mobile number, the following is what I have done so far, but it does not appear to work.

I need it to raise a validation error when the value passed does not look like a mobile number. Mobile numbers can be 10 to 14 digits long, start with 0 or 7, and could have 44 or +44 added to them.

```
def validate_mobile(value):
    """ Raise a ValidationError if the value looks like a mobile telephone number.
    """
    rule = re.compile(r'/^[0-9]{10,14}$/')

    if not rule.search(value):
        msg = u"Invalid mobile number."
        raise ValidationError(msg)
```

Comment: have a look at this example: http://www.anthoniraj.com/python-code-for-mobile-number-validation/

Comment: Could you provide some examples, which are valid, please?

Comment: @ Alexey Are the answers not valid? They appear to work. could you explain, it would really help if I have misunderstood. thanks

Comment: @User7 the answers treat your question differently. Currently the answer from MikeM is more graceful and more exact to your description.

Comment: I'm surprised how many people try to do it all in one regex. It's easier if you start by rejecting anything but numbers and approved separators and a leading +, then delete the separators, and THEN use a regex. But the phonenumbers package is almost certainly a better idea still. Its a big world out there.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The following regex matches your description

```
r'^(?:\+?44)?[07]\d{9,13}$'
```

Comment: To make it clear, I am not claiming that this is a good mobile phone validation regex, but just that it fits the definition of mobile numbers in the question.

Comment: Can you provide the regex for standard mobile number?

Answer (score 29):

I would recommend to use the [phonenumbers](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/phonenumbers) package which is a python port of Google's libphonenumber which includes a data set of mobile carriers now:

```
import phonenumbers
from phonenumbers import carrier
from phonenumbers.phonenumberutil import number_type

number = "+49 176 1234 5678"
carrier._is_mobile(number_type(phonenumbers.parse(number)))
```

This will return True in case number is a mobile number or False otherwise. Note that the number must be a valid international number or an exception will be thrown. You can also use [phonenumbers](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/phonenumbers) to parse phonenumber given a region hint.

Comment: I wont recommend this as it does not throw an exception when an alphabet is encountered in the string.

Comment: If it returns fals, isn't that good enough?  For me, this has been far best so far.

Comment: As per PEP8, `_is_mobile` should be considered private. However, `phonenumbers.number_type` can be used as is, and seems to return `1` for mobile numbers, and `0` for fixed phone numbers. The documentation is sparse, though...

Comment: I entered my landline for testing and it returned True. I am most certain my landline is not a mobile number. Per documentation:     # In some regions (e.g. the USA), it is impossible to distinguish between
    # fixed-line and mobile numbers by looking at the phone number itself.
    FIXED_LINE_OR_MOBILE = 2.... so this library is not reliable for determining mobile numbers in the US, maybe elsewhere as well

Answer (score 3):

I would try something like:

```
re.compile(r'^\+?(44)?(0|7)\d{9,13}$')
```

You would want to first remove any spaces, hyphens, or parentheses though.

Comment: I'd replace `(0|7)` with `[07]` as MikeM did. Also it would match phones like `+0123456789` and `+7123456789`.

Answer (score 2):

These won't validate +44 numbers as required. Follow  **update**: John Brown's link and try something like this:

```
def validate_not_mobile(value):

    rule = re.compile(r'(^[+0-9]{1,3})*([0-9]{10,11}$)')

    if rule.search(value):
        msg = u"You cannot add mobile numbers."
        raise ValidationError(msg)
```

Comment: @User7. Perfect? The above will validate e.g `gobbledegook999999999999999999999999999999`.

Comment: @User7 MikeM is correct, my bad. Please see his answer. MikeM, chill thanks for pointing out the error, but don't take offence we are are here for the same thing.

Comment: A Software QA engineer walks into a bar. He orders a beer. He orders two beers. He orders -1 beers. He orders 999999999 beers. He orders a Salvador Dali Painting ....

Answer (score 0):

```
import phonenumbers
from phonenumbers import carrier, timezone, geocoder
from phonenumbers.phonenumberutil import number_type

number = "+911234567890"
print(carrier._is_mobile(number_type(phonenumbers.parse(number))))
print(phonenumbers.parse("+911234567890"))

my_number = phonenumbers.parse("+911234567890")
print(carrier.name_for_number(my_number, "en"))

print(timezone.time_zones_for_number(my_number))

print(geocoder.description_for_number(my_number, "en"))

print(phonenumbers.is_valid_number(my_number))
print(phonenumbers.is_possible_number(my_number))
```

The reason is that the is_possible_number() method makes a quick guess on the phone number's validity by checking the length of the parsed number, while the is_valid_number() method runs a full validation by checking the length, phone number prefix, and region.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a validate function using [phonenumbers](https://pypi.org/project/phonenumbers/) package

for example:

```py
import phonenumbers

def validate_phone_number(potential_number: str, country_code: str) -> bool:
    try:
        phone_number_obj = phonenumbers.parse(potential_number, country_code)
    except phonenumbers.phonenumberutil.NumberParseException:
        return False
    if not phonenumbers.is_valid_number(phone_number_obj):
        return False
    return True
```

Answer (score -1):

## Python validation mobile number for sololearn

```
str = input()
import re
if len(str)==8:
   pattern=r"[981][^.......$]"  
   match = re.match(pattern,str) 
   if match: 
      print("Valid")
   else:
      print("Invalid")
else:
   print("Invalid")
```

Comment: The pattern `[981][^.......$]` and the expected input length don't match the requirement in the question. Also, you're assigning a value to `str` which will overwrite the internal `str` type.