# I am trying to validate phone numbers in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, azure-databricks

I am trying to validate the Phone number in my dataframe. The code should flag the number as home or Mobile or Invalid

This is specific to UK phone number validation. And i tried Regex but it wont flag the number.

```
import pandas as pd 
import re
# display(df)
# df.head()
df['Phonenumber']=df(df.withColumn('Phone_Number_Validity', if(isValid(df)):       
       # print ("Mobile Number")      
       else : 
       # print ("Home Number")))
display(df)
```

Getting Syntax error

Comment: You should try to edit and format your question in order to be more readable.

Comment: Welcome to the StackOverflow! Please go through the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), the [Help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) sections to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers. Please also have a look at [How do I ask](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions#10812).

Comment: I don't see here any ReGex patterns in your code.

Comment: The basic regex is not working. Also, i want it to be flagged. The code you see is using Pandas

Answer (score 1):

You have not created an `isValid()` function.

Look [here](https://regex101.com/r/zX2cE5/1) for a regex to validate UK phones and create a `isValid` function which compiles checks if the string matches the regex like this:

```
regex = '((^\(?(?:(?:0(?:0|11)\)?[\s-]?\(?|\+)44\)?[\s-]?\(?(?:0\)?[\s-]?\(?)?|0)(?:\d{2}\)?[\s-]?\d{4}[\s-]?\d{4}|\d{3}\)?[\s-]?\d{3}[\s-]?\d{3,4}|\d{4}\)?[\s-]?(?:\d{5}|\d{3}[\s-]?\d{3})|\d{5}\)?[\s-]?\d{4,5}|8(?:00[\s-]?11[\s-]?11|45[\s-]?46[\s-]?4\d))(?:(?:[\s-]?(?:x|ext\.?\s?|\#)\d+)?)$)|(\(?[2-9][0-8][0-9]\)?[-. ]?[0-9]{3}[-. ]?[0-9]{4}))'
m = re.match(regex, input)

if m:
    print("True")
else:
    print("False")
```

Comment: Getting the followig errorFile "<command-745688837684174>", line 6
    m = re.match('\'+regex, input)
                                  ^
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal

Comment: SELECT * FROM emailvalidation WHERE Phonenumber REGEXP '((^\(?(?:(?:0(?:0|11)\)?[\s-]?\(?|\+)44\)?[\s-]?\(?(?:0\)?[\s-]?\(?)?|0)(?:\d{2}\)?[\s-]?\d{4}[\s-]?\d{4}|\d{3}\)?[\s-]?\d{3}[\s-]?\d{3,4}|\d{4}\)?[\s-]?(?:\d{5}|\d{3}[\s-]?\d{3})|\d{5}\)?[\s-]?\d{4,5}|8(?:00[\s-]?11[\s-]?11|45[\s-]?46[\s-]?4\d))(?:(?:[\s-]?(?:x|ext\.?\s?|\#)\d+)?)$)|(\(?[2-9][0-8][0-9]\)?[-. ]?[0-9]{3}[-. ]?[0-9]{4}))$'

Comment: This is another way to doing it

Comment: I changed my regex, you could try again.
Your code in the comment above is using SQL, which you don't mention at all in your question.

Comment: Still no luck. Can someone share the code in python/pyspark where i can validate UK phone numbers and flag them

Answer (score 1):

You could give the [phonenumbers library](https://github.com/daviddrysdale/python-phonenumbers) a go.
Example code for validating a phone number in Great Britain:

```
import phonenumbers

def validate_phone_number(phone_number):
    try:
        return phonenumbers.is_valid_number(phonenumbers.parse(phone_number, region="GB"))
    except phonenumbers.phonenumberutil.NumberParseException:
        return False
```

If you want to check if the number belongs to a mobile carrier you could check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21608354/10862659).