Check if string contains numbers and plus sign in python
I'm trying to build a reminder app and want to check whether the string the user gives contains only a plus symbol and numbers. Ideally it would start with a plus as this string will represent the country code and phone number to send the reminder to.
I tried the startswith() method along with the isdigit() method. However since I have to use and compare the two conditions it doesnt work seeing as the first character is a plus symbol and therefore not a digit.
I have also considered regex, however I can't find anywhere how to represent the + symbol in the string seeing as the + symbol actually means one or more occurences of a character as opposed to the plus symbol character itself.
Any help would be greatly appreciated

Can you addd your code, inputs and expected outputs?

Regex of \+ would be a literal plus symbol

As a simple first step, you could iterate over each character in the string and check if it is a plus sign, a digit, or something else.  What is the difficulty?

Some helpful resources: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/280435/escaping-regex-string, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4202538/escape-special-characters-in-a-python-string, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean

if first char is + then you should skip it when you check isdigit - text[1:].isdigit(). And when first char is not + then you should check full text  - text.isdigit().

For phone numbers, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16135069/how-do-i-validate-a-mobile-number-using-python

I think regex is best for an application like this. It is true that + is a special character in regex, so in order to treat it as a literal '+' the escape character \ can be used. This treats any character after it as its literal form rather than any special properties.
I recommend using a regex tester website to help you such as Regex101. There's many ways you could check for a phone number. Does it include '-'? Are you expecting a +X-XXX-XXX-XXXX format? And so on.

An example regex for this problem could be "A phone number must begin with a +. The country code follows and is anywhere from 1-3 digits. The phone number follows and has the 3-3-4 digit format. Hyphens separate each part. An example input is +X-XXX-XXX-XXXX (country code with 1 digit)."
r'^\+\d{1,3}\-\d{3}-\d{3}\-\d{4}$'.
Then use the regex library to check with something like:
if re.match(regex, some_string):
    print("Valid phone number.")


I'll break down each part.
r'' to format it as a regex expression
^ is the start of the expression
\+ to check for a literal '+' character
\d{1,3} to check for 1-3 digits (the country code)`
\- to check for a literal '-' character
$ is the end of the expression

/^(\+?\d{1,3}|\d{1,4})$/

use this for python :
if re.match(regex, some_string):
print("Valid phone number.")

see this question : Regex for country code

That's a regex for a country code, yes, not a whole phone number


how to represent the + symbol in the string seeing as the + symbol
actually means one or more occurences of a character as opposed to the
plus symbol character itself

Enclose said character in [ and ] that is in your case regular expression might be [+][0-9]+

This would match more than just phone numbers, though
